# How to generate shadow fields getters and setters on java fx?

Tags: java, plugins, model, javafx-2, getter-setter

Using javafx beans properties is a quick way to bind ui controls to actual values, but when dealing with memory we tend to find that this has a high cost that not all computers could support. So instead of spending lots of resources we can just use lazy instantiation with a shadow field. The thing is that you'd normally want to use this lazy evaluation whenever you have a bean with large number of properties (since each property is an object in itself and therefore the number of Object would become large) and since there is no plug in for generating getters and setters for shadow fields this could become a little bit tedious.

This is an example of lazy instantiation

```
private StringProperty first name;
private String _firstname = "";

public String getFirstname(){
return (first name != null)? first name.get() : _firstname;
}

public void setFirstname(String newFname){
if(first name != null){first name.set(newFname)};
else{_firstname = newFirstname};
}

public final StringProperty firstnameProperty(){
if(firs name == null){first name = new SimpleStringProperty(this,"firstname", _firstname)};
return firstname;
}
```

This should be considered to be implemented in the model class when a large number of properties exist, for saving memory but it is also very tedious considering we'll use this when we're having a huge amount of properties and here comes my question: Isn't there an easy way to quickly type this out(if possible not to type it)?

Comment: I think the best way to do this is with an IDE plugin/addon, so the question is - which IDE do you use?

Comment: I use both netbeans and eclipse

Comment: But I haven't find any